WPF MahApps.Metro visualizar objetos de pantalla principal al llamar pantalla secundaria
estoy empleando MahApps.Metro funciona perfectamente cuando mando a llamar pantalla tras pantalla, pero si deseo ejemplo llamar el formulario principal y luego mandar a llamar un formulario secundario sin cerrar el primero, al perder el focus o el hilo principal lo deja como si estuviera vacio a simple vista y solo muestra el title bar de otro color inclusive pero sin objetos
solo si mando a llamar pantalla por pantalla lo muestra   MahApps.Metro, pero si tengo una pantalla principal y mando a llamar una secundaria la primera  pareciera queda vacio sus objetos a la vista

Eso es raro.. tenes un ejemplo de como lo hiciste??? un [mcve]?? les preguntaste a ellos en algunos de sus canales?
